# A method to realize large-capacity data processing with GCP using Meanstack

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Meanstack is running on GoogleCloudPlatform and ChromeBrowser is trying to process a large amount of data.
If resource_size: 298mbyte is passed from the Chrome browser to the program, the data body becomes 0byte and an application error occurs. Please let me know if there is a solution using GoogleCloudPlatform when creating such data
If there is no way to do this, can I only do server-side processing with PHP running on the server?

Thank you.
Best Regards,
Tatsuya

Comment: Which service? Most have an HTTP body limit of 32 MB.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you! I used chrome for browser. Best Regards Tatsuya